# Conditional Mutual Information, Chain Rule

Tags: information-theory

Consider three discrete binary random variables -- A, B, C.

I have calculated `I(A;B)` and `I(A;C)`, but I want to calculate `I(A; BC)`

I'm having trouble implementing this.

From reading [this paper](http://www.ece.tufts.edu/ee/194NIT/lect01.pdf) I have an idea, but can't get it to work out in python.

I have these functions (python 3)

`def entropy(X, Y):
    probs = []
    for c1 in set(X):
        for c2 in set(Y):
            probs.append(np.mean(np.logical_and(X == c1, Y == c2)))
     return np.sum(-p * np.log2(p) for p in probs if p > 0)`

and

`def calc_MI(x, y, bins):
    c_xy = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins)[0]
    mi = mutual_info_score(None, None, contingency=c_xy)
    return mi`

But I'm not sure how to move forward, thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean you want to compute `I(A;B|C)`?

Comment: I don't think so, no. If you look at section 4.3 of the paper, under "Properties" of conditional mutual information, there is the chain rule. I want to use that to compute `I(A; B C)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compute `I(A;BC)` you do not necessarily have to use the conditional mutual information. `I(A;BC)` is the mutual information between `A` and the joint variable `BC`.

In python you might encode `BC` with 4 values: 0,1,2,3 for all the combinations of values for `B` and `C`. You might do this using: `2*b + c` where `b` can be either 0 or 1 and `c` the same. Then you can compute the mutual information between `A` and `BC`.

Otherwise as you point out, you can use the formula from the paper: `I(A;BC) = I(A;B) + I(A;C|B)`. In this case you have to use conditional probabilities.

Comment: Thank you. Encoding the combinations of values is the key I guess.